# starting JBoss from command line fails with ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.ValidConnectionChecker

Tags: java, command-line, jboss

the way I start JBoss from command line is following:

javaw.exe -Dprogram.name=run.bat -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:/projects/myappserver/target/staging/jboss-4.2.3.GA/bin/../lib/endorsed -Xms128m -Xmx812m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dfile.encoding=Cp1250 -classpath C:\projects\myappserver\target\staging\jboss-4.2.3.GA\bin\run.jar org.jboss.Main -c myjboss

this is something I've taken from process explorer when JBoss is running fine from Eclipse

in my app, I use a datasource and in deploy/mysql-ds.xml I have specified class 
com.mysql.jdbc.integration.jboss.MysqlValidConnectionChecker which should implement the 
ValidConnectionChecker.

When I start the command mentioned above, I get
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.ValidConnectionChecker

I can see this interface in jboss-common-jdbc-wrapper.jar in c:\projects\myappserver\target\staging\jboss-4.2.3.GA\server\myjboss\lib\

Is this an issue of classpath? Why does it work from Eclipse? Thanks for any response which would help me to start JBoss from command line.

Comment: JBoss server can be start by running the run.bat file. It's not required to use the eclipse run file.

Answer (score 0):

J Boss server can be start by running the run.bat file. It's not required to use the eclipse run file.

Refer the below link which will helpful to you.

https://www.coderanch.com/t/90561/JBoss/Error-starting-Jboss-Command-Prompt

https://community.jboss.org/wiki/StartAndStopTheJBossApplicationServer?_sscc=t

Comment: hi ... thanks
I thought that I am running JBoss run.bat. It's the part '
javaw.exe -Dprogram.name=run.bat '
which I run from bin folder. I'll have a look at the links you have provided.

Comment: Hi, I had a look, but it didn't seem to help me. My problem is that I specify this in mysql-ds.xml:

`<valid-connection-checker-class-name>com.mysql.jdbc.integration.jboss.MysqlValidConnectionChecker
</valid-connection-checker-class-name>`

and copy mysql-connector-java-5.1.17.jar to myjboss\lib folder. Even though, error I get, it points to interface which this class implements and that is ValidConnectionChecker from jboss-common-jdbc-wrapper.jar present in myjboss\lib as well. So, I don't really get this... any help please?